# how to define optional path parameters in Play Framework routes

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I have the following overloaded functions to match my **routes** file

```
  def getMessage() = getMessage(None, None, None)
  def getMessage(campaignID: Option[String]) = getMessage(campaignID, None, None)
  def getMessage(campaignID: Option[String], revision: Option[Int]) = getMessage(campaignID, revision, None)
  def getMessage(campaignID: Option[String], revision: Option[Int], transactionID: Option[Int] ) = Action.async { implicit request =>

    db.getDocument(campaignID, revision, transactionID)
    .map(result =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(result))).recover {case ex: IOException => InternalServerError("Please install MongoDB")}
  }
```

Here's my **routes** file:

```
GET     /message                                                          controllers.Application.getMessage()
GET     /message/:campaignID                                              controllers.Application.getMessage(campaignID:String)
GET     /message/:campaignID/:revision                                    controllers.Application.getMessage(campaignID:String, revision:Int)
GET     /message/:campaignID/:revision/:transactionID                     controllers.Application.getMessage(campaignID:String, revision:Int, transactionID:Int)
```

How do I make it work so that campaignID, revision and transactionID are completely optional on the REST call? Right now, I am receiving the following error:

```
[error] /Users/superman/conf/routes:9: Compilation error[Using different overloaded methods is not allowed. If you are using a single method in combination with default parameters, make sure you declare them all explicitly.]
[error] GET     /message/:campaignID                                              controllers.Application.getMessage(campaignID:String)
[error]                                                                           ^
[error] (compile:playRoutes) @6oo852mf7: Compilation error in /Users/superman/conf/routes:9
[error] - application - 

! @6oo852mf7 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/message/A/1/124] ->

play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompilationException: Compilation error[Using different overloaded methods is not allowed. If you are using a single method in combination with default parameters, make sure you declare them all explicitly.]
        at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$9.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:152) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$9.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:150) ~[na:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$.compileRoutes(RoutesCompiler.scala:150) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$4.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:127) ~[na:na]
        at play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler$$anonfun$4.apply(RoutesCompiler.scala:126) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28) ~[na:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Comment: You can give a default value to the parameters that not given in the GET request, do you know it ? Play does not support the option as parameters in the route file.

Comment: You can only have optional query string parameters, but not optional path parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need only a single method in your controller, like this:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def options(id:Long, revision: Int, transaction: Int) = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(s"id: $id, revision: $revision, transaction: $transaction"))
  }
}
```

And then you can declare your routes like this:

```
GET     /options                              controllers.Application.options(id:Long = 1, revision:Int = 2, transaction:Int = 3)
GET     /options/:id                          controllers.Application.options(id:Long, revision:Int = 2, transaction:Int = 3)
GET     /options/:id/:revision                controllers.Application.options(id:Long, revision:Int, transaction:Int = 3)
GET     /options/:id/:revision/:transaction   controllers.Application.options(id:Long, revision:Int, transaction:Int)
```

Comment: Thanks! But for me those default values are problem too because I will have to query mondoDB based on those fields (id, revision, transaction). Having a default value means my query may yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to define 3 entries in routes file.Just have one entry with below given signature:

```
controllers.Application.options(id:Option[Long], revision:Option[Int], transaction:Option[Int])
```

And in controller just check all 3 using `id.isDefined, revision.isDefined, transaction.isDefined` like this.And then you can get the value using .get method.